# Why I get a "Application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000018)" when I build program in vs2015 sometimes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I write a c++ program using visual studio 2015 community in windows 7(64bit).

When I begin to run the program, sometimes the program will terminate, and a dialog box shows up, saying

> "Application failed to initialize properly 0xc0000018".

Why do I get this error sometimes rather than always? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: show the [MCVE] that exhibits this behavior. Most likely you have Undefined Behavior

Comment: It is a low-level operating system kernel fault, it comes out of ZwMapViewOfSection().  The kind of function that's used to map DLLs.  Very little you could do to trip this error yourself, this is environmental.  You need to get your machine healthy again.  Focus on malware, particularly the shrink-wrapped kind that programmers voluntarily install, shoddy anti-virus software can do this.

Answer (score -1):

Besides a bad application itself (that should be possible to track in the debugger):

This might be a corrupted Windows installation or Windows registry as well. Do you see it only for your application or also for some other applications?

It might be caused e.g. by some DLL that is built to be installed at fixed address, it might be a virus, malware, or even antivirus getting into the way.

Some of the reasons/solutions are mentioned e.g. here: https://superuser.com/questions/610495/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc0000018-windows-8-x64

The first thing to try is to remove the contents of `APPINIT_DLLS` in the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\­Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Windo­­ws` - some of the DLLs loaded there might cause the problem.

The reason you do not see it every time could be that sometimes there might be some other DLL loaded on the particular address before the DLL with the fixed address requirement is to be loaded, so the conflict only occurs then.